# I want to add two objects at one position in listview programmatically

Tags: android, listview

i want to add two objects at one position in listview programmatically.
i have tried ArrayAdapter but it didn't worked.Could you please help?
Thanks

Comment: by Objects , do you mean , TextView & ImageView kind of ?

Comment: yes TextView and DatePicker

Comment: can you please explain question.

did't get what you want.

Comment: I not sure you can do it using ArrayAdapter, Here is an example with BaseAdapter http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

Comment: I want to add TextView having text-"Date" and DatePicker to select date. Both at one position side by side

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating you own view and populate listview with that view by writing your own adapter. See [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), exactly how to do that.